# Java sine and cosine

Tags: java, graph, trigonometry

Hello I am trying to create a java program that allows you to graph an equation and its been working well so far until I wanted it to graph cosine and sine functions. I am confused on how I can do this when sine and cosine return doubles but drawLine only takes in integers. I am new to java so this may be easy but if you could help I would appreciate it.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.awt.geom.*;

class PlotGraph extends JFrame{


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g.drawLine(50, 300, 550, 300); //x axis
    g.drawLine(300, 550, 300, 50); //y axis
    //Orignin x = 300 y = 300

    double xmin, xmax;
    double y;
    xmin =(0);
    xmax = 100;
    double x = xmin;

    double form = Math.cos(x);

    double last_y = 300-(form);

    for (x = xmin+1; x<=xmax; x++){
    double newForm = Math.cos(x);
    y = 300-(newForm);
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x-1+(300), last_y, x+300, y));
    last_y = y;

    }




}

public static void main(String [] args) {

    PlotGraph graph = new PlotGraph();
    graph.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    graph.setSize(600, 600);
    graph.setVisible(true); 
    graph.setTitle("PlotGraph");

}
}
```

Comment: Depending on how you want cosine to look, you may want to multiply it by a constant, like 10 or 50 to show up better on your graph. Otherwise, cosine will only return values from -1 to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Since Math.cos() returns a value between -1 and 1, casting to int will result in only 3 values -1, 0 and 1, and will almost always be 0.

What you want to do is multiply the double by a large constant to create a range of integers:

```
    y = 300-(int)(300d * newForm);
```

Note the "d" after the 300: that makes the 300 a double, making the result if the multiplication also double, this keeping fine granularity.

Comment: As 'newForm' is already a double, the 'd' in '300d' contributes nothing.

Comment: Well I'm just confused on how I draw cosine and sine since drawLine() only takes int's an dnot doubles.

Comment: The `(int)` is called a cast.  When used before a value, it converts (or 'casts') it to the type indicated in brackets.  So in this instance, the double value of `(300d * newForm)` is converted to an int.  Since `300` is also an int, `y` is therefore also an int.

Answer (score 1):

Use Line2D.Double objects, a Graphics2D Graphics object and have the Graphics2D object draw the shape with its `draw(...)` method.

Comment: what types of arguments does draw(..) take?

Comment: @user2106089: it takes a Shape argument or any class that derives from the Shape type such as Line2D.

Comment: I am trying to use this line and it's saying the package Line2D does not exist
g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x-1+(300), last_y, x+300, y));

Comment: @user2106089: have you imported `java.awt.geom.*`?

Comment: Okay that got it to compile but now no lines graph in my created window.

Comment: I also updated my code above to what I am currently compiling

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the double to an int.

```
int y = 300 - (int) (Math.cos(x) * scaleFactor);
```

And as Aiias said:
cos will only return values between -1 and 1. So make sure you multiply it by a constant factor or you will lose the value after casting.

Answer (score 0):

After properly scaling, you might try either of:

- typecast the `double` to an `int`:  `int i = (int)d;`
- rounding, which returns `long` which must by typecast to `int`: `int i = (int)Math.round(d);`